# Metro version of Internet Explorer doesn't open from Start Screen of Windows 8

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use the IE10 App without making Internet Explorer the default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default)

Is there a way I can force Metro version of Internet Explorer to open? If I click the Internet Explorer tile from the Start Screen, it still opens up the Desktop version - not sure why this is happening.

What should I look at to debug this problem?