# How do I get the Modern UI of Firefox in Windows 8?

Tags: firefox, windows-8, modern-ui

Mozilla mentions

> Elm is the experimental repository where most of our Metro development work has been happening.

Now, I grabbed the latest nightly from the Elm repo, installed it & then despite starting it from the start screen, I was still provided the desktop version.

Is there a way I can get the <s>Metro</s> Modern UI of Firefox in Windows 8? Do I need to add some extra command line arguments or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, firstly, there seems to be a quirk in Windows 8: only the default browser can be launched with Modern UI. I have tested with IE, FF and Chrome on the Enterprise Evaluation and they will all launch the Desktop version unless set as default. Additionally, as soon as a browser is set as the default handler for HTTP/HTTPS, any other running Modern UI is instantly closed. [More information is available at this question](https://superuser.com/q/490415/117590).

So, I have it running fine. There were a few things I did, any of which may be responsible:

- Installed an [older Firefox build](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/tinderbox-builds/elm-win32-metro/1348486515/) (FF 18), specifically the [installer executable](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/tinderbox-builds/elm-win32-metro/1348486515/firefox-18.0a1.en-US.win32.installer.exe)
- Set as default for all via Control Panel => Programs => Default Programs => Set Default Programs => Nightly

  [[image: Screenshot]
  <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5RJP.png)
- When the Modern UI version launched, but hung with a blank screen, I closed it via Task Manager, set IE back to default, and set Nightly to default again. At this point, the Modern UI version of FF worked.
- Installed the [latest elm build](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-elm/) (FF 19, 24-Oct-2012 06:06), again from the [installer executable](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-elm/firefox-19.0a1.en-US.win32.installer.exe). Restarted.

So, now I have Nightly running with Modern UI:

[[image: Screenshot of FF Modern UI]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEiEL.png)

[[image: Screenshot of FF Modern UI, snapped]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZgmZ.png)

Comment: yeah, I had to set it as default to get it running. Stupid move, if you ask me :\

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't *quite* work right yet. Using a shortcut to the executable (Might be in Program Files (x86))

```
"C:\Program Files\Nightly\firefox.exe" -metrodesktop
```

with that new parameter opens up the Metro version of Firefox Elm on the regular desktop.

Chances are this will be fixed in future builds

[image]

Comment: I'm really wondering if they're completely programming the wrong way (not starting as a Metro app and thus not being able to go into the Metro environment) or there's some trick to use Metro applications in the desktop, because this is definitely weird...

Comment: It's  supposed to be based on fennec for windows phone so its definately an odd one

Comment: I'm going to have to unmark this as accepted answer - this didn't work - had to set a browser as default for it to start in Metro Mode

Comment: The defaultness was something I *did* set and have no luck with. Chrome lets you swap between modes *if* its default so i guess its a hard and fast rule for some reason. Bloody strange if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is here, I just installed the nightly build myself without issues.

It didn't seem to activate the metro version (when launched from the start screen) until after a reboot, but from then on it worked just fine.

Keep in mind though it is still in NIGHTLY status, and many bugs should be expected.

PS: same thing happened with metro chrome. On first install it was desktop only, but once reboot, metro worked.