# How do I set Firefox Nightly as my default Metro browser in Windows 8?

Tags: firefox, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the Modern UI of Firefox in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/491067/how-do-i-get-the-modern-ui-of-firefox-in-windows-8)

The latest Nightly build of Firefox claims to have support for the Metro (Modern) UI. How can I change my default Metro browser from Internet Explorer to Nightly?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek this is not the dupe of that question as here OP is asking how to set it default and the problem not launch in ModernUI after setting it default.

Comment: @slhck can you take a look on this question as I don't think this is the dupe of that question As OP is just asking how to set it default an the problem is after setting it default. I think both are diff.

Comment: If it was the default, it would launch in modernUI. It dosen't cause the modernUI portion is broken. If you really feel this question should be reopened, consider asking on meta. I VERY strongly feel this is an exact dupe, and the answer dosen't work as is, anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to control panel and select the option "Default Program" now a dialog box will appear select the first option "Set you default programs". Now the list will be load then search out Firefox and select it now you will see the "Set this program as default". See the screen shot as I've set the Chrome to default you can do it for Firefox. That's it.

[image]

Comment: I've done this, but any links clicked from Modern-UI open in the desktop version of Nightly. How do I use the Modern-UI version of Nightly?

Comment: Right click on the Firefox icon and select the properties. Now in the target after giving a space add `-metrodesktop` and apply it. Beware don't delete the whole value.

Comment: @Suchipi don't forget to mark it accept if it solve the problem. :P

Comment: Does it actually work though? I was testing it earlier and it didn't work - I got the modern UI in the desktop instead

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: More than likely since it's still in beta, the [contextual launching feature](http://superuser.com/a/491855/138343) doesn't work properly yet.