# Where does Windows 8 put the exe of the default browser for Modern UI?

Tags: windows-8

I was trying to some hack with Win-8 and I found something which is really gonna out my mind. When I set the default browser to the IE then its icon become Modern UI and I can't see the option **`Open file location`** at the bottom when I select it by right click. But if I don't set it default then it became a desktop version icon and show up the option when I select it.

Same is for the Google Chrome when I checked it.

IE icon when it is not set to default, I can see the option `open file location`.

[image]

Google Chrome icon when it is set to default.

[image]

Google Chrome of desktop version when it is set to default.

[image]

So my question is where does Modern UI keep exe of the default browser? And why the default browser has Modern UI icon and non-default browser has desktop version icon.

Comment: The file isn't moved, the default install location of course is `Program Files\WindowsApps`, but the file isn't moved once installed.  The default location of Metro IE10 is likely stored along with IE10, its unlikely stored in the same location, because its not your traditional Metro application.  This sounds like a pure programming bug on the Chrome side of things.

Comment: @Sathya: I don't see how this is a duplicate.  One question asks about the shortcuts, or whatever data determines which tiles appear on the homescreen.  The other asks where the executable is stored.  shortcuts != executables

Comment: @BenVoigt agreed, reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new default browser doesn't create a new executable.  As you can read on this [Building Windows 8 blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150911230954/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/14/metro-style-web-browsing-one-engine-two-experiences-no-compromises.aspx) entry, there is just one browser engine (the EXE) and two skins.  One suitable for touch, and one suitable for desktop.

You can only have one ModernUI interface browser.  Whatever browser is set as default (IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc) will be accessible in Metro mode.

Comment: Then why the option disable for the default set browser? And why IE/chrome icon change in desktop version if I set one of them to default?

Comment: There are two experiences: one for browsing with Windows RT and touch, and the other is the general desktop usage.  If you have an ARM devices like Windows Surface, then you will only be able to use the touch experience.  However, MS had to allow another browser to be the default, remnants from the monopoly war.

Answer (score 1):

Default Metro apps are stored in `Program Files\WindowsApps`, but IE's EXE ought to be located in its own Program Files folder as always (no separate EXEs for desktop and Metro versions). Similarly for Chrome, check its installation dir.

In general, Metro apps do not have a single file that contains the program, like Desktop apps normally do. Metro/Windows Store apps (.appx packaged) run in App Containers that contain many different files/folders.

As for the icons, only your default browser will be available in Metro. In other words, if you set Chrome as your default browser, you’ll lose access to Metro IE, and vice versa. Thus when you set the Metro version of a browser as the default, the icons for the other installed browsers automatically changes since their desktop version is now launched instead.

Comment: I updated my question. I want to know why the icon is being change when we change the default option for the browser's and also where is the exe/icon for such thing?

Comment: @avirk: Edited my answer.

Comment: I know about that but I need a reason for that. Hope you are someone help me.

Comment: Reason? I don't understand. You want to actually know *why* Microsoft decided to impose this limitation? I doubt anyone outside of MS knows.

Comment: Yep! That's why I put my question, may be someone out of MS know it. :P

Comment: @avirk - Then your question is not on topic on Super User.  This problem is likely caused by a problem with the Metro Chrome, which by the way, is in beta still.

Comment: @Ramhound: Actually, that limitation seems to be entirely thanks to MS, and not a fault of Chrome. It works the same way with FF Metro as well (which admittedly is also in beta). Have you successfully managed to access the metro version of a non-default browser?

Comment: @Karan - They are all in beta.  It is possible to launch a Metro version of a browser, the Metro version of Google Chrome doesn't follow the guidelines, and Firefox's Metro version isn't complete.

Comment: @Ramhound: "It is possible to launch a Metro version of a browser" - I never said it wasn't possible at all. What I said was, it *seems* you cannot launch the Metro version of a non-default browser. I'm still looking for any official word about this though. All I've found till now is various sites stating in their reviews that this is a Windows limitation. I'm not sure they have all come to the same erroneous conclusion, but then again, stranger things have happened.

Comment: @avirk: I have answered your query about the distinction between metro/desktop browser icons in detail [here](http://superuser.com/a/491855/138343).