# How do I force all links to open in the Desktop browser?

Tags: browser, windows-8

When I click a link from a Modern UI app, it opens in my default Modern UI browser. How do I force all links, regardless of source, to open in the desktop browser? Ideally, the Modern UI browser would not open at all, except possibly if I manually opened it.

I am currently using Firefox Elm (a Nightly build), but answers for IE10, Chrome, or any other browser that supports both a Modern UI and Desktop interface would be great too.

Comment: While this has been answered for IE10, it would be great to have an answer addressing Firefox/Chrome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IE10 has an option in the desktop Internet Options settings dialog under the Programs tab to specify that links and tiles be opened in Desktop Mode:

[image]

(it's disabled here as it's set by Group Policy)

The Group Policy location for these settings is in both User Configuration and Computer Configuration at 
`Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Settings`:

[image]

Comment: So, basically, it's browser specific/controlled?

Comment: @Bob: Yes. Read the activation/contextual launching portion of my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/491855/138343) for details.

Comment: So how would it work when Chrome is the default browser?