# Immersed versus 'normal' version of chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I force all links to open in the Desktop browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/493936/how-do-i-force-all-links-to-open-in-the-desktop-browser)

I installed chrome, and now I have 2 ways to open chrome: if I open chrome from the metro-tile  menu, I get the full-screen, immersed, windows-8 style chrome. If I start the link I got on my desktop, I get the windowed version.

Apart from the fact that I would like to know how I might do that on purpose, I also want to know what's going on so I can use the windowed version (I prefer that for a browser) from all links I have, especially the one in the menu.

Comment: The second half of your question has already been asked: [How do I force all links to open in the Desktop browser?](http://superuser.com/q/493936/117590)

Comment: Bob: That question addresses only IE10, not Chrome.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan The *current answer* is about IE. The question, from the start, has been about browsers in general with Firefox Elm, IE10 and Chrome all used as examples. (Also, please use `@name` to ping someone about the reply)

Answer (score 0):

From [chrome help pages](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2762879),

> Due to system limitations, only plug-ins using Pepper API, such as Flash, Native Client, and Chrome PDF Viewer will function properly when Chrome runs as a Windows 8 app.

Plugins like Java will not work in *immersed* mode

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing 0_o

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't have direct bearing on the question. It wasn't me.