# full-screen browsing with IE10 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, fullscreen, internet-explorer-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use the IE10 App without making Internet Explorer the default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default)

I have updated to Windows 8 and got Internet Explorer 10, but I don't get the full screen mode, is just like another desktop app. All links on the Windows Store Apps (Bing, News...) redirect to the old desktop and open my default browser (chrome). I have set IE as default browser but that not solve the problem. I have been looking on the IE10 options but I don't see this option. How can I solve this?

[image: full screen IE10]
Maybe this info help:

- Windows version: Windows 8 Pro 64 bits
- Installed Browsers: Firefox, Chrome (default), Opera, IE10
- I have seem other people with the same version and is working

**Edit:** Is possible to have IE10 by default for windows 8 apps links and Chrome for Desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the Metro version of IE10, you need to have IE set as the default browser. That's the case for any browser: To use the Metro version of it, you must have it set as the default.

You stated that you tried setting it as the default, but it didn't work. There are multiple ways to set defaults in Windows, and sometimes they don't cover all the bases, so make sure you followed the procedure below. YOu stated later that Chrome is now the default browser, again. If you have Chrome set to be the default, you cannot use the Metro version of IE10.

**To set IE10 as the default:** Open *Control Panel*, click on *Programs*, and then *Set Program Access and Computer Defaults*. In the window that appears, select *Custom* and click the down arrow next to it to view its configurable options. Under *Choose a default browser*, select *Internet Explorer* and click to check *Enable Access To This Program* (if not already selected). Click OK and exit out of the Control Panel. Links should open in IE.

Once you set IE10 as your default browser, you should be able to launch the Metro version by opening the Start Screen and searching for Internet Explorer. Invoking your default browser from Metro apps or from the Start Screen will always open its Metro version (if one exists). Note that if you launch IE10 using a desktop shortcut or a pinned taskbar button, it will open the desktop version of the program.

However, if you simply want a full-screen browsing experience in IE10 in the same way that you could make IE9 or earlier versions full-screen in older versions of Windows, you can always launch the desktop version of IE10 and press <kbd>F11</kbd> to toggle full-screen mode. As it's still the desktop version of the software, it will expect a mouse & keyboard-driven interface for the user. It isn't the same as the Metro version of the browser. However, if full-screen is all you need and you don't want to have to change default browsers, this can be an alternative option.

Comment: Thanks, the http protocol was uncheked on the setting (via Control Panel). Now I have counted 3 ways to configure default browser o.O

Comment: @Tom Yeah. They're for multiple scenarios: (1) Automatically ask the user, (2) One-click setting for everything, (3) Fine-grain control for different situations within one over-arching category. Usually most people only have to worry about (1) and (2).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming IE is your default (although not clear giving your wording), there are options with how IE can be used when opening links.  From the Internet Options window within Desktop IE10, go to the Programs tab and select one of the options in the drop down under Opening Internet Explorer

- Let Internet Explorer decide
- Always in Internet Explorer
- Always in Internet Explorer on the desktop

Choosing 'Let Internet Explorer decide' may use both the full screen and desktop versions depending on how you follow a link (from the desktop, from within a modern UI app, from a pinned item on the start screen, etc)

[image: See image]

Comment: Interesting... I will check this. Using this can I have Chrome by default for Desktop and IE10 for Windows8 apps?

Comment: No, your default browser can only be one browser.  IE maybe the only one to support the split between metro and traditional desktop apps (at this time?).

Comment: @edusysadmin, what do you mean by "split between ..."? Do you mean the ability to "jump" between the two instances or do you mean the screen-splitting-feature of Windows 8?

Comment: Most people view IE10 as a "metro" IE10 and a "desktop" IE10.  Not being a Chrome or FF user since moving to IE9 I'm not sure if either Chrome or FF operate in that manor in Win8.  So other browsers might act like the setting 'Always in Internet Explorer on the desktop'

Answer (score 1):

There are two user interfaces for Internet Explorer 10 in Windows 8: The desktop application and the "Metro" application. The "Metro" application seems only to show up in the start menu, if Internet Explorer is the default browser.

To set IE as your default browser, go into the control panel (on the desktop: mouse to the right bottom/top screen edge -> gearwheel -> *Control Panel*) to *Programs* -> *Set your Default Programs* and choose *Set this program as default* for Internet Explorer.

Comment: I think a better description is there are two UIs to IE10 rather than two versions.  Its the same core accessible via either the desktop or the metro interface.

Comment: They don't share things like cookies though. http://superuser.com/questions/494663/is-is-possible-to-share-cookies-between-windows-ui-ie-and-desktop-ie