# full-screen browsing with IE10 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use the IE10 App without making Internet Explorer the default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default)
>   [full-screen browsing with IE10 on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/505706/full-screen-browsing-with-ie10-on-windows-8)

I have updated to Windows 8 and got Internet Explorer 10, but I don't get the full screen mode, is just like another desktop app. All links on the Windows Store Apps (Bing, News...) redirect to the old desktop and open my default browser. I have been looking on the IE10 options but I don't see this option. How can I solve this?

[image: full screen IE10]
Maybe this info help:

- Windows version: Windows 8 Pro 64 bits
- Installed Browsers: Firefox, Chrome (default), Opera, IE10
- I have seem other people with the same version and is working

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is how to change your default browser?
If you do so then you have to look into your control panel under programs -> default programs -> set default programs. There you have to select IE10 as your default browser.
This should solve your problem