# Cannot use both Google Chrome and IE10 in metro mode

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, internet-explorer, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use the IE10 App without making Internet Explorer the default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default)

When I set at all defaults to IE10 then I can access IE10 in Metro mode from the tile,but not Google Chrome.And when I set Chrome to all defaults then when I open IE10 , it opens in metro mode.

How to use both in Metro mode simultaneously ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use more than one browser in Modern UI mode. Only the default browser is launched in Modern UI mode.