# Why is my default browser setting being ignored?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I have Google Chrome set to be the default browser, but all hyperlinks are still opened in Internet Explorer 10.

Chrome *is* the default application for **.html** files, which is odd because I never selected a default program for .html files.

What should I do to open all hyperlinks in Chrome by default?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no difference between being the default for the desktop and being the default for Metro/Modern UI. There's only one place to set this, and it should cover both. You can however set only the extension .html to default to Chrome, and still have hyperlinks go to Internet Explorer.

*It would not surprise me to find an entry in the registry that contradicts the default desktop program vs default metro, however there's no setting or place in the control panel to change this. Take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default). The answer which received the bounty seems to indicate there is a registry entry somewhere that may or may not indicate an MUI app being set as default, however it may not have any effect on the behavior of hyperlinks.*

---

Open up start and search for `Default Programs`:

[image]

Now choose `Set your default programs`:
[image]

Take a look at Chrome and see what it has set. Mine only had 3 out of 18:
[image]

**There's a difference between .html extensions and HTTP protocol!** Setting Chrome as the default for .html will cause .html files from the desktop or explorer to open in Chrome. We want to make sure that Chrome is the default for HTTP protocol.
[image]

Make sure `HTTP, URL:HyperText Transfer Protocol` and `HTTP, URL:HyperText Transfer Protocol with Privacy` are both set.

Answer (score 2):

That could be happening because you only set the default browser for desktop or metro, not both - make sure that it's been set as default in each.
From [google chrome help](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95417):

1. Click the Chrome menu  on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Settings.
3. In the "Default browser" section, click Make Google Chrome my default browser.

> Windows 8 users: **To launch Chrome as a Windows 8 app** from your Start Screen, follow the steps above and set Chrome as your default browser. Learn more about Windows 8 apps

**EDIT**

Some programs always force Internet Explorer to open links, there's nothing you can do about that.
If the steps above don't help, can you check if other programs open link with chrome (e.g. the default "mail" app)?

Comment: how to set default browser for both metro and desktop.your steps say how to set chrome as default browser,which I have already done.I am using the same old desktop version of chrome

Comment: @vishesh you need to do it twice: once inside chrome for desktop, once with chrome for metro. I actually just tried to reinstall it and this was done automatically: the steps above were needed only for old versions.

Comment: so this means we need the metro version of chrome,just for opening links by default in chrome.I can't really upgrade to metro chrome due to my slow connection :(

Comment: @vishesh you should *already* have chrome for metro, as it gets installed along with the desktop version. Try pressing "WIN" and then typing "chrome": you should see it listed.

Comment: "once inside chrome for desktop, once with chrome for metro" - Even for old versions, this sounds like a Chrome bug. Users should be required to do this only once in either version.

Comment: Where do you set defaults for Metro?

Answer (score 1):

go to Preferences in Firefox>Security and select "Remember History". This had bugged the hell out of me until I changed this setting. Guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

1.Click the `Chrome menu` on the browser toolbar.
2.Select `Settings`.
3.In the `Default browser` section, click Make Google Chrome my `default browser`.

I think this can help