# internet explorer 10 opening in desktop mode by default

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use the IE10 App without making Internet Explorer the default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default)

The internet explorer 10 in windows 8, is opening in desktop mode when launched from the new start menu tile.This started happening when I changed the default browser to google chrome.

what should I do to open it in metro mode by default when launched from start menu ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE10 can only be metro mode when it is made a default browser. The same rule goes for the other browsers.

Comment: looks like I am never gonna use ie in metro mode :)

Comment: We could hack Metro mode for all browsers by writing a script to continually sets the active browser window as default browser.