# How to open Internet Explorer in "desktop mode" and not the "Windows UI mode" in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, windows-8.1

I just needed a new laptop and Windows 8 came with it...

One of the issues we're frustrated most about is those applications that open in the "Windows UI" mode (formerly known as Metro-style). Such as Internet Explorer.

We hate the "Windows UI" mode for Internet Explorer because we

- Don't see tabs
- Can't just close it normally (I know, there are other ways, but we prefer the close icon)
- Internet Explorer switches to "suspended" mode when toggling applications which causes audio to stop running

I don't seem to be able to start Internet Explorer in "desktop mode", while there are supposed to be two modes possible (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/browse-web-internet-explorer-tutorial)).

Internet Explorer is still the default browser.

I read in other questions ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/498632/internet-explorer-10-opening-in-desktop-mode-by-default) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default?lq=1)) that Metro style is only possible when it's the default browser. But I actually can't succeed in the reverse: **Is desktop mode possible at all when Internet Explorer is the default browser?**.

Comment: Simplest way is to not click on links while in a Windows Store application in other words use desktop applications and click on links which will always use the desktop version of IE

Comment: @Ramhound To me it seems IE opens in windows ui mode when I launch the IE tile from the start screen. Shouldn't this open in the desktop mode?

Comment: Only if you pin the IE Desktop Tile. By default your likely clicking on the Modern UI IE tile.  You can also just hit CTRL+D and launch IE like you did when you were using Windows 7

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound I can not check it right now, but you're reference to Modern UI IE tile let me to this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/03/26/launch-options-for-internet-explorer-10-on-windows-8.aspx I should now be able to configure those settings easily

Comment: The article is in reference to Windows 8.0; there were not so insigificant changes to the Start Screen in Windows 8.1.  Not sure the reason for the link to the article.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to the Start Screen, and type in "Internet Options". Go to the *Programs* tab, and click the checkbox with "Open Internet Explorer tiles on the desktop."

Also, going to Internet Options from the Control Panel works if you can't search.

Comment: Super. I'm working on a non-english windows, so typing "internet options" didn't work, but I went to "Control Panel" > "Internet Options" and marked that checkbox. Thanks.

Comment: For "Internet Options" to display requires option "View By" (normally on the upper right) set to the 2nd or 3rd, "Small Icons" or "Large Icons", respectively.