# How to pin a website to the Windows 8 Start screen without Internet Explorer as default browser?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, start-screen

I'm not sure if I like the whole idea of Start screen yet, but I would find it more useful with Stack Overflow as a tile in the group.

Is there a way to add the Stack Exchange sites to this screen and if so how?

My default web browser is Chrome.

Comment: If you switch to chrome in windows 8 mode, the option simply becomes available under bookmarks. And in case you don't like windows 8 mode: the tile still works after you switch back to desktop mode.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only way that I can think of is by using a app called OblyTile.

[OblyTile](http://www.xdafileserver.nl/index.php?dir=Other/Oblytile)

What you want to do is create a tile that opens up Chrome or whichever browser you want to use but in this example I will use Chrome. Once you have found the file path for Chrome, in the arguments section below it you might want to use "--homepage http://stackoverflow.com" so that when you open the tile it opens up StackOverflow. (Someone can feel free to correct me on this)

Comment: Worked like a champ

Comment: No need to use OblyTile for this, see my answer.

Answer (score 24):

No need to use special programs to achieve this! First method works for all browser, and can be used to create shortcuts to all range of things. Second method is a Chrome only feature.

What we do is just to create a shortcut somewhere to the browser you'd like to open with websites as parameters.
Right click, select *New* -> *Shortcut*
Select the browser you'd like. Mozilla Firefox is in Program Files, Google Chrome is in AppData.

[image]

Give the shortcut a name and finish. Then right click the new shortcut and select *Properties*. In the *Target* field, add the webpage to open.

[image]

Press OK, and then right click the icon again and select *Pin to Start*.
[image]

**Chrome only:**
Chrome even has special built in features for this. Open up the webpage you want in Chrome. Then click on the menu icon, select *Tools* and then *Create application shortcuts*. Make sure the *Start Menu* is ticked and press *Create*. Tada! Now you have a Tile on your start menu, with the proper icon for the website, even.

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Too bad you didn't post this yesterday :)

Comment: This other question ( http://superuser.com/questions/500134/how-to-pin-a-website-to-the-windows-8-start-screen-with-internet-explorer-as-def ) is for IE users only; you should post this there

Comment: @Mondain hmm, that one got closed.. :)

Answer (score 8):

**Method for Internet Explorer** (If not default browser)

**Edit:** This only works for IE and is [not](https://superuser.com/a/499491/68111) [necessary](https://superuser.com/a/499492/68111) if you already use IE as your default browser..

You can copy a URL shortcut to the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` folder, and it will appear as a tile on the Start Screen.

For example:

- drag a shortcut from your browser to the desktop
- drag the shortcut from the desktop to the Start Menu folder

For either method, **if you want to change the icon**, check out the program in Matthew Wong's answer, [OblyTile](http://www.xdafileserver.nl/index.php?dir=Other/Oblytile).

Comment: Now that is clever

Comment: its not really necessary though

Comment: @TaylorGibb some people, myself for example, don't have access to the Metro version of IE because IE is not our default browser.

Comment: do you mean you cant use IE if its not your default browser?

Comment: I just added a shortcut in that folder, but it doesn't seem to show on the start menu?

Comment: @Razor really, can I try to reproduce what you did?

Comment: @TaylorGibb you can't use the metro ui of IE if its not set the defualt.

Comment: oh I guess I learnt something then :)

Comment: @TaylorGibb yes, that's right. See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default).

Comment: @Louis right click on the desktop -> new -> shortcut -> www.google.com -> Google -> drag and drop on `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` -> press win key and no shortcut name "Google"

Comment: @Razor Sorry, you are right this isn't an answer. I used IE to create the shortcut, but it creates a `Pinned Site Shortcut` and not what I was expecting.

Comment: @Razor: When I create a shortcut like that, it also doesn't work. When I drag & drop the favicon out of IE onto my desktop and move *that* shortcut to the given folder, it works.

Comment: If you like my answer you should upvote it, not copy it.

Comment: @Matsemann I honestly didn't see it.

Comment: Ah, np then. Just leave your answer as it was, including our method. :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're using IE10 just click the [image] button on the address bar and click **Pin to start**.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Chrome is my default

Comment: This must be a Metro or RT thing because when I click on IE I don't get this interface from Start.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the Metro Internet explorer.
2. Browse to the website.
3. Click on the Pin and choose "pin to start".

Heres a picture of what it looks like on the start screen.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Chrome is my default

Comment: Well why didn't you add that useful piece of information to your question? You got the answer you deserve.

Comment: I didn't think about it at the time; it was my mistake

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in Chrome without anything additional. Just do the following:

- Click on the settings button in the upper right
- Hover over "Bookmarks"
- Select "Pin this page to Start Screen..."

I don't know what version of Chrome added this, but it is available in the current version (23.0.1271.91 m)

Note: Chrome must be launched in Windows 8 Mode for this option to appear.

Comment: How do I launch Chrome in windows 8 mode you ask ?https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2762879?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

None of the previous suggestions here really did what I wanted. So my solution is very similar to Louis', and it works fine with Chrome and probably other browsers as well:

- Drag the favicon from the browser's address field to
  the desktop.
- Drag the created shortcut from the desktop to the folder

  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
- Go to the Start page, and move over to the page with all apps (the
  down-arrow in the lower left corner).
- Locate your shortcut, right-click and select "Pin to start"