# Using Metro style in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: windows-8, browser, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use the IE10 App without making Internet Explorer the default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default)

I'm using Windows 8 Pro with Internet Explorer 10 on, and I downloaded Google Chrome, setting it the default browser. After that I saw that when I click on the Internet Explorer shortcut on the Start screen it opened me IE10 in the Desktop. Now I want to ask: can I use the IE10 App in Metro Style without making her the default browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one Metro browser at a time, you installed Chrome which took over as the default browser. Microsoft designed it this way on purpose.

Comment: Is there a reason that Microsoft has for this setting?

Comment: Yes they are limiting only one browser to interact with the Metro Style experience.