# Internet opens up in desktop mode on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

For some reason when I click my IE tile on my windows 8 laptop it automatically loads up in desktop mode.
How do I get it back to opening up properly like it did before in IE 10?

Comment: Also see [How do I get back the Metro version of Internet Explorer on Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/506933/how-do-i-get-back-the-metro-version-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-8) and linked questions.

Answer (score 0):

Open IE>Tools>Internet Options>Programs>Uncheck "Open Internet Explorer tiles on the desktop"