# Internet Explorer tile disappeared in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use the IE10 App without making Internet Explorer the default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default)

I installed Firefox, and now I no longer see the Internet Explorer tile. What caused this and how can I get it to stay there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.
2. Type `Set your default programs` and press enter.
3. Select Internet Explorer and click `Set this program as default`.
4. The Modern UI Internet Explorer tile should be back:

   [image]

If not:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>.
2. Type `Internet Explorer`.
3. Right-click `Internet Explorer`:

   [image]
4. Select `Pin to Start`:

   [image]

Comment: "Set your default programs" didn't return anything when I tried it on a Windows 8.1 installation (English).

Answer (score 2):

When you installed Firefox, I presume you set it as your default browser.  This caused the IE tile to disappear.  You can just pin it back to Start, or you can set IE as your default browser.  Either way will get the tile back.

[Source](http://www.intowindows.com/fix-internet-explorer-metro-tile-missing-from-start-screen-in-windows-8/)

Answer (score 1):

Go to all apps, right click Internet Explorer in the list, and select pin to start. This should bring it back into the main tile list, and normally it shouldn't unpin itself.

You can then move it around into a location you like.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> button.
2. Start typing "Internet Explorer".
3. It will be on your screen soon. Go to it, and right click it.
4. A menu bar will appear at the bottom of the screen. Click on "Pin to Start".

It is easy enough.