# Why do all Windows 8 Metro browsers require they have Default Browser status?

Tags: windows-8, browser, file-association, modern-ui

In order to use IE 10, FF Nightly, or Chrome in Metro mode (As a Windows 8 fullscreen, pinnable app), I have to set it as the default, immediately forcing all other browsers to only run on the desktop. This seems strange to me, as I feel any programmer should be able to put their layout engine into a Metro app without making said app the default browser. **Is there a technical or political reason why all Metro browsers require Default status?**

Comment: Detailed answer already posted here with links to official docs: [Is it possible to use the IE10 App without making Internet Explorer the default browser?](http://superuser.com/questions/490415/is-it-possible-to-use-the-ie10-app-without-making-internet-explorer-the-default)

Comment: I don't know if this is a duplicate; their question asks _how_ to use two metro browsers, whereas mine asks _why_ they can't

Comment: Did you happen to read my answer quoting official MS docs at length? Since that answers your query (to the extent it can by non-MS people), it has been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Questions can be duplicates if another question's answer happens to answer this question?

Comment: Questions may be worded differently (obviously) but overall if they're discussing the same issue and more importantly if users directed to the duplicate 'target' receive answers that solve their problem, then it's a valid duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS defines this way:

> Windows 8 also continues to offer desktop app experiences as found in
>   previous versions of Windows. **In Windows 8, the browser that the user
>   sets as the default for handling webpages and associated protocols may
>   be designed to access both new experiences as well as the traditional
>   desktop experience**.  This type of browser is the new experience
>   enabled desktop browser.  This guide describes how to create such a
>   browser.
>
> **Tiles in the Start screen activate the browser in the new user
>   experience when the browser is the default. When the browser is not
>   the default, tiles activate the browser in the desktop.** This same
>   behavior also applies to a browser’s secondary tiles.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=243079

I don't see a (technical) reason why MS did this.

Comment: The reason I see for this is that MS wanted to be the only browser maker that could put browsers in metro, and didn't want anyone else using full applications in metro, as to monopolize Windows 8, but the EU fined them, so they had to allow alternate browsers.